# Java char is also an int?

Tags: java, type-conversion, equivalence

I was trying to get some code done for class:

```
public int getValue(char value) {
    if (value == 'y') return this.y;
    else if (value == 'x') return this.x;
```

Since I might not be able to return anything in the end, it told me to do this at the end:

```
return value;
```

This surprised me because the return type for the method was of type `int`. Yet, it was telling me to return a `char`! I'm using eclipse, and accustomed to the endless number of warnings and stuff, this was a major surprise.

So, is a `char` really an `int`? Why is this happening?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2

Comment: Each char has a char code associated with it.  The char code is an integer.  When you cast char to int you get the char code for that character...

Comment: So it would essentially return the ascii value associated with the char?

Comment: @brso05 What you are calling "char code" is a UTF-16 code unit, one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint, one base codepoint and any number of "combining character" codepoints form a grapheme, which is one textual element, such as Ç.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17) states

> When a return statement with an `Expression` appears in a method
>   declaration, the `Expression` must **[be assignable (§5.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) to the declared
>   return type of the method**, or a compile-time error occurs.

where the rules governing whether one value is assignable to another is defined as

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - [a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

and

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening
>   primitive conversions:
>
> - `char` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double

and finally

> A widening primitive conversion does not lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value in the following cases, where the
>   numeric value is preserved exactly: [...]
>
> A widening conversion of a `char` to an integral type `T` zero-extends the
>   representation of the `char` value to fill the wider format.

In short, a `char` value as the expression of a `return` statement is assignable to a return type of `int` through widening primitive conversion.

Answer (score 2):

A `char` is smaller than an `int`, so you can return it and it will prepend zeroes to make a longer number. That's not the right thing to return - in your case I'd probably throw an exception instead; however, the editor suggested it because it's something that you're *allowed* to return and you need to return something.

The following code is legal:

```
char c = 'h';
int i = c;
```

Answer (score 2):

In computing, everything is numbers! Just bits and bytes.

`int`, `char`, `byte`, `short` and `long` are just numbers. A `char` is just a number that the compiler knows is usually used for displaying the character represented by the particular number (e.g. 32 = space, 48 = zero, etc).

A String is a sequence of numbers and other stuff, so a bit more complicated. We don't want to go there.

An `int` is a four byte number and a `char` is a two byte number, so you can fit any `char` number in an `int`.

The designers of Java just decided they would let you convert from char to int without requiring any special casts or conversions.

Answer (score 2):

A `char` is not an `int`. However, it is an *integral type*. That is to say, it's considered to be a whole number that can be converted to and from other integral types (`long`,`short`,`byte` and `int`), according to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1).

Basically what this means is that it is assignment-compatible to `int`. Its value is between 0 and 65535, and if you assign it to an `int` or cast it to an `int` and print it, you'll get the UTF-16 value of the character it represents.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit and natural conversion from `int` to `char` and vice-versa. Note that you thus have the usual arithmetic defined on `char`m which comes very handy when you want, let's say, to iterate on the alphabet :

```
for (char c='a' ; c<='z' ; c++) { ... }
```

However, note that a `char` is 2 bytes long whereas an `int` is 4 bytes long, so casting an `int` down to a `char` may result in an integer overflow.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Basically, it will implicitly cast to an int, and this is a one way only road?

Comment: Anyways, perfect answer. I didn't know it would just cast it implicitly... I'm used to having everything explicit (I'm come from a pythonic world) :)

Comment: Please note that a `char` is two bytes long. It's basically an unsigned `short`.

Comment: Um, what?  Java won't implicitly cast `int` to `char.`  You can do it explicitly, but it doesn't work the same both ways.

Answer (score 1):

By definition (in java) a char is an 8bit unsigned integer. (0 to 256)

An int an 32bit signed integer. (−2.147.483.648 to 2.147.483.647)

```
char a = 65;                    //65 is the ASCII Number of 'A'
System.out.println(a);
>>> A

b = a + 1
System.out.println(b);
>>> B
```

java autoboxing converts char to int and vice versa

Answer (score -2):

Hope this little example solves your confusion:

```
public int getValue(int value) { 
    if (value == 'y') 
        return this.y; 
    else if (value == 'x') 
        return this.x; 
}
```

If you pass `char` as an `int` like `getValue('x')`, it would return the value of the `int`.

Comment: But what if value is `d`? Then I don't want to return `x`.

Comment: it will return the Ascii valdue of the returned char