# Why does this equation return the answer it does?

Tags: java

I am Confused as to why this returns 1;

`(char)('0' + 11) = ;` why?

Full code below where ending = 1;

```
 char[] ending;
       char a = (char)('0' + 11/10); 
        ending = new char[]{a, (char)('0' + 11)};
        System.out.println(ending);
```

Comment: If `ending` is an array, then this program should not print `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Char value of `'0'` is 48.
- 48 + 11 = 59
- Char value of 59 is `';'`.

You can check `char` values in integer value in any ASCII Character Set in internet.

In Java, `char` can be use as a `int`, `short`, `byte`, `long` with values between 0 and 65535 without any casting.

A better explanation is found in: [Java char is also an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717898/java-char-is-also-an-int)

Comment: Internally java chars are 2 bytes so more like shorts than integers.

Comment: Java characters are UTF-16 encodings of Unicode characters. You can look into a unicode table for characters that are up to 15 significant bits.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning '1' to variable a. '0' + 11/10 => '0' + 1
You are assigning a two letter string to endings. Le first letter is a ('1') the second is a semi colon. ('0' + 11).